# Remove last character of NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I've got some trouble 'ere trying to remove the last character of an NSString.
I'm kinda newbie in Objective-C and I have no idea how to make this work.

Could you guys light me up?

Comment: "Could you guys [light me up?](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/light+up?r=75&src=ref&ch=dic)". The usage you're looking for is "[enlighten](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/enlighten?r=75&src=ref&ch=dic) me".

Answer (score 202, accepted):

```
NSString *newString = [oldString substringToIndex:[oldString length]-1];
```

Always refer to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html):

- [`substringToIndex:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/substringToIndex:)
- [`length`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/length)

---

To include code relevant to your case:

```
NSString *str = textField.text;
NSString *truncatedString = [str substringToIndex:[str length]-1];
```

Comment: My Xcode doenst seem to 'understand' this "substringToIndex", he doenst even autowrite. Is it right?

Comment: As long as you `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` and are using Mac OS X 10.0 or later/iOS 2.0 or later, then yes it's right. Make sure to download the documentation set in Xcode settings to get method autocompletion.

Comment: @markus are you calling it in a NSString? Just in case, post the line of code where you want to use it.

Comment: @darvids0n maybe it's being called in something other than a string.

Comment: If you're using Mac OS X prior to 10.0, I'm impressed. (Yes, it did exist! Sorta.)

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan OpenStep apparently already [had it](http://www.gnustep.org/resources/OpenStepSpec/FoundationKit/Classes/NSString.html). Maybe way before MacOS X itself. But what is MacOS X prior to 10.0? I can't remember exactly, I just remember there was the Server version which was released in 1999, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: I'm trying to get a NSString from a UITextField and remove the last character.

Comment: @markus I updated the answer. Give it a try and post your results

Comment: BTW, on the `[oldString substringToIndex:[s length]-1];`, the correnct would be: `[oldString substringToIndex:[oldString length]-1];`

Comment: @sidyll I meant Mac OS X Server, yes, and to a lesser extent NeXTSTEP/OpenStep.

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
s = [s substringToIndex:[s length] - 1];
```

Comment: this is vulnerable to crashes when NSString length is 0, add validation :

**if ([s length] > 0) {**
 s = [s substringToIndex:[s length] - 1];
**}**

Answer (score 5):

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithString:@"ABCDEF"];
NSString *newString = [string substringToIndex:[string length]-1];
NSLog(@"%@",newString);
```

**You can see = ABCDE**

Comment: Please format your code using the"{}" option within the editor. :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
NSString = *string = @"abcdef";

string = [string substringToIndex:string.length-(string.length>0)];
```

If there is a character to delete (i.e. the length of the string is greater than 0) 
     `(string.length>0)` returns 1, thus making the code return:

```
 string = [string substringToIndex:string.length-1];
```

If there is NOT a character to delete (i.e. the length of the string is NOT greater than 0) 
     `(string.length>0)` returns 0, thus making the code return:

```
string = [string substringToIndex:string.length-0];
```

which prevents crashes.

Answer (score 1):

This code will just return the last character of the string and not removing it :

```
NSString *newString = [oldString substringToIndex:[oldString length]-1];
```

you may use this instead to **remove the last character** and retain the remaining values of a string :

```
str = [str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,[str length] - 1)];
```

and also using **substringToIndex** to a NSString with **0 length** will result to crashes.

you should add validation before doing so, like this :

```
if ([str length] > 0) {

   str = [str substringToIndex:[s length] - 1];

}
```

with this, it is safe to use substring method.

NOTE : Apple will reject your application if it is vulnerable to crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Simple and Best Approach

```
[mutableString deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange([myRequestString length]-1, 1)];
```